How to properly block the administrator page in Joomla using Nginx proxy?
I want only some networks to access the Joomla administration page ("/administrator"). To do this, I made the configuration below. It is working. I would like to know if this would be the best configuration.
The proxy_intercept_errors does not work for "/administrator" rule. Default 403 error page is shown.
examplesite.conf:
server {
    listen              443 ssl http2;
    server_name         examplesite.com;

    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    include /usr/share/nginx/html/nginx-errors-ptbr/nginx-errors.conf;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/examplesite.bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/examplesite.key;

  
    # logging
    access_log          /var/log/nginx/examplesite.access.log;
    error_log           /var/log/nginx/examplesite.error.log warn;


    # Allow /administrator only for specific IPs
    location /administrator {
         allow 192.168.0.0/24;
         allow 192.168.1.0/24; 
         deny all;
         proxy_pass http://192.168.2.20:8080;
         include    examplesite/proxy.conf;
    }


    # reverse proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.2.20:8080;
        include    examplesite/proxy.conf;
    }
}
 
# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name examplesite.com;
    return      301 https://examplesite.com$request_uri;
}


proxy.conf:
proxy_http_version                 1.1;
proxy_cache_bypass                 $http_upgrade;

# Proxy headers
proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection        $connection_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Host              $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Forwarded         $proxy_add_forwarded;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

# Proxy timeouts
proxy_connect_timeout              60s;
proxy_send_timeout                 60s;
proxy_read_timeout                 60s;

nginx-errors.conf:
error_page 400 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/400.html;
error_page 401 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/401.html;
error_page 402 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/402.html;
error_page 403 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/403.html;
error_page 404 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/404.html;
error_page 405 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/405.html;
error_page 406 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/406.html;
error_page 407 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/407.html;
error_page 408 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/408.html;
error_page 409 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/409.html;
error_page 410 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/410.html;
error_page 411 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/411.html;
error_page 412 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/412.html;
error_page 413 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/413.html;
error_page 414 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/414.html;
error_page 415 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/415.html;
error_page 416 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/416.html;
error_page 417 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/417.html;
error_page 418 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/418.html;
error_page 421 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/421.html;
error_page 422 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/422.html;
error_page 423 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/423.html;
error_page 424 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/424.html;
error_page 425 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/425.html;
error_page 426 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/426.html;
error_page 428 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/428.html;
error_page 429 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/429.html;
error_page 431 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/431.html;
error_page 451 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/451.html;
error_page 500 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/500.html;
error_page 501 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/501.html;
error_page 502 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/502.html;
error_page 503 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/503.html;
error_page 504 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/504.html;
error_page 505 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/505.html;
error_page 506 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/506.html;
error_page 507 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/507.html;
error_page 508 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/508.html;
error_page 510 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/510.html;
error_page 511 /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/511.html;

location ^~ /nginx-errors-ptbr/errors/ {
    ssi on;
    internal;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    allow all;
}

location ^~ /assets/css/style.css {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/nginx-errors-ptbr/errors;
    allow all;
}

location ~* montserrat-(400|700).(eot|woff2|woff|ttf|svg) {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/nginx-errors-ptbr/errors;
    allow all;
}

403.html:
<html>
<head>
  <title>Forbidden - <!--# echo var="host" default=""--></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <h2 class="main_error-code">403</h2>
    <h1 class="main_error-title">Forbidden</h1>
    <p class="main_error-message">O servidor se recusou a autorizar a solicitação.</p>
    <p class="main_error-message">Lamentamos o inconveniente.</p>
    <a class="main_error-link" href="javascript:window.history.back();">Voltar</a>
  </main>
</body>
</html>

Possible solution to the problem:
# Allow /administrator/ only for specific IPs
    location /administrator/ {
         proxy_pass http://192.168.2.20:8080;
         include    examplesite/proxy.conf;

         allow 192.168.0.0/24;
         allow 192.168.1.0/24; 
         deny all;

         error_page 403 =302 /;
    } 


The problem with proxy_intercept_errors for the /administrator may probably occur because Nginx does not intercept errors for proxied requests unless they are returned from the backend server. In the case of deny all, Nginx generates the 403 error itself, rather than receiving it from the backend, which may prevent this error from being intercepted via proxy_intercept_errors.
Try explicitly specifying an error page for this case in the /administrator block.
The deny all directive in /administrator section blocks access to resources, including CSS files. To fix this, allow access to CSS and fonts.
Example:
location /administrator {
allow 192.168.0.0/24;
allow 192.168.1.0/24;

deny all;
proxy_pass http://192.168.2.20:8080;
include examplesite/proxy.conf;

location ~* \.(css|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)$ {
root /usr/share/nginx/html/nginx-errors-ptbr/errors;
allow all;
}
}

Judging by the port 8080, you are using Apache for the backend. If so, you can also configure blocking using the .htaccess file.
For .htaccess, this rule will be rewritten as follows:
<Directory "/path/to/directory/administrator">
Require ip 192.168.0.0/24
Require ip 192.168.1.0/24
Require all denied
</Directory>


I added the nginx-errors.conf file configuration.

Checking again, I noticed that the error page displayed is not the default one. But rather my custom page that was loaded without using CSS. So the custom page and the default page are very similar. Other error pages load the CSS normally.

Try allowing CSS and fonts in the /administrator block. I've added an example.

I tested your example but the CSS is still not loaded. In further testing I noticed that the slash "/" at the end of the url matters. If I type "https://examplesite.com/administrator"  the CSS is loaded with the page. If I type "https://examplesite.com/administrator/" the CSS is not loaded.

The default is "https://examplesite.com/administrator/".

While researching, I saw that one of the ways to restrict access to "/administrator/" would be to use a redirect to the home page using this configuration: "error_page 403 =302 /;". Another piece of information I saw was to put the CSS inside the HTML file, but I haven't tested it.
